# Xcode & Quartz Composer - perfect standalone

Tags: xcode, xcode5, quartz-composer

I have build my standalone app from a QC patch using Xcode. Everything works good however, I was wondering if it is possible to hide the QC patch when I do Show package nd I go inside my app.

Also, is there a way to use the stand alone even if people don't have the plugin I have used in my patch such as Kineme 3d, and there is a way to implement them inside my app?

thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Use [Kineme QuartzBuilder](http://kineme.net/QuartzBuilder):

- It encrypts your composition, making it difficult for an end-user to extract and copy your composition.
- It automatically bundles the plugins your composition uses (except Kineme AlphaBlendMode, which you need to manually add).
- If you add a note at the top level of your composition containing your Kineme3D license key, the plugin will work on other systems when your composition is loaded.  Obviously you should not distribute compositions that contain your license key, unless you use QuartzBuilder to package them (since then the license key is encrypted).

Comment: Thank you so much, I have tried to use the Quartz Builder unlicensed just to have a test on a small patch, however, even if I check the box show parameters, the parameters box does not appear.. Is because is not the licensed one or because I'm using 10.8? I wanna make sure it works before I buy it

Comment: In order for the Published Parameter Display to work, you need to do 3 things: 1. In your composition, publish at least one input port, and 2. In your composition, enable the Parameters Visible value in the Window Outputs patch, and 3. In QuartzBuilder, go to Advanced Settings > Published Parameter Display and select HUD or Panel (instead of None).  (I just tested it in Mac OS 10.8, and it works.)

Comment: Thanks so much, got it working now… How can I add a note with my license key? Is it the yellow that you use for notes?

Comment: Also I was wondering for ages, sometimes in compositions I see objects that have the patch time input in it.. how can I do that?

Comment: To add a note, right-click on a blank area of the editor window and select "Add Note".

Comment: Some patches support external timebase.  Right-click on the patch, and select Timebase > External.